# Drupal 7: how to create hierarchical node structure

Tags: drupal

The company has departments. Ex.: MyCompany - London department, New York department etc. Each department has own news, prices, photogallery. Structure:
- MyCompany
--- London
----- News
------- news1
------- news2
------- news3
----- Price
------- price1
------- price2
--- New York
----- News
------- news1
------- news2
------- news3
----- Price
------- price1
------- price2

I looked at 'Node Reference', but couldn't get URL like. /london/news/1, because parent url(/london) not presented in pathauto pattern. 
How can i get such a structure?

Comment: I found this post on drupal.org: http://drupal.org/node/1044980

Comment: No way to do it without token?

Comment: I'm stuck on Drupal 5 (huge code base, long story), I was surprised you couldn't do it directly. Token is a good module to have, though.

Comment: i was wrong. I wanted to say - taxonomy instead token. Sorry. Of couse token is a useful module. But there is no way to insert parent url alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use or Drupal's menu system or Drupal's taxonomy to make such relations.
The relation is not always defined by URL.

Answer (score 0):

The [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module may be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Where would this structure be used? I think you could either use taxonomy terms instead of nodes (terms in 7 are fieldable entities and you can use views to make them do pretty much anything a node can) or create a taxonomy hierarchy and associate each term with a node.

Answer (score 0):

Node Heirarchy module.

Though it looks like it's not ready for release for D7.  Aren't they already up to 8?

Nice explanation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oz3xkF819c0